# Run time error- Cannot find module "child process" when executing python script in ionic 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, typescript, ionic3

I'm going to execute a python script through an Ionic 3 application in the button click event. I have used [Python-shell](https://github.com/extrabacon/python-shell) in order to accomplish this task.

Below is my code snippet in 'home.ts'.

```
import { PythonShell } from 'python-shell';

 rundata(){
  PythonShell.run('C:/ChathuS/PycharmProjects/Profiling module new/Profiling module/data.py', function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Executed data.py');
  });}
```

In the 'home.html', I use a button click event to call the above function as follows.

```
 <button ion-button (click)="rundata()" *ngIf="facebook.loggedIn">  
    <ion-icon name="logo-facebook"></ion-icon>  Analyse profile 
 </button>
```

[image: Error_image]

This gives me following error in the browser.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in client side , you need to understand this

`You wan't to bundle your code for the browser, and the browser doesn't know about processes and child processes.`

at most write your web services and make get/post request and implement your python code there.

Check this out if you still want to do this

[Git](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/66)